# Parse.com and Android - sending push notifications conditional to new user signing up

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

Parse.com and Android question.

My Parse.com backend consists of users who have signed up to use my app.  Some users are given "admin" status (also defined in the Parse backend), which comes with certain privileges - one of which is to approve or deny new users who live in the same town or city they do.  For example, admins who live in Town XYZ can grant access to other people who live in town XYZ.

My question is this.  Using the Parse.com Push Notification service, can I set up a push notification so that whenever a new user requests access (i.e., a new row is added to the backend), a push notification is sent to the admin of that town/city to alert them that a new user is requesting access to the app.

I have read through the Parse.com documentation on push notifications for Android here:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/Android

I didn't see my issue addressed.  This may be because so much of this terminology is new to me, that I read right over it.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know i'm late , but if you haven't figured it out, You can use Advance targeting for this.

Add a new column field in the parse installation class , this field will only be for the admins in the towns.

Then when a user requests access, the user can send a client side push notification using advance targeting .

```
 ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> pq = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
              pq.whereEqualTo("admin", "string consisting of the admin");

              // Send push notification to query
              ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
              push.setQuery(pq); // Set our Installation query
              push.setMessage("push notification text");
              push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: can u see thi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303082/failed-to-recieve-notification-sending-on-button-click-using-parse-com-android