# Failed to receive notification sending on button click using Parse.com Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Using [Parse](https://parseplatform.org/) as cloud database now I have button in Android app. On button click I want to send push notification to more than one user (using username). it's sending the notification successfully but failed to receive in target devices.
Here is the code I am using to send successfully but here I do not specify username or multiple users as target just set Channel as "".

WORKING CODE WITHOUT SPECIFY USERNAME:

```
pushNotifcationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
            ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
            ParseQuery userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
            userQuery.whereEqualTo("username","aamir");
            query.whereMatchesQuery("user",userQuery);
            parsePush.setChannel("");
            parsePush.setQuery(query);
            parsePush.setMessage("First Message");
            parsePush.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
                
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(TAG, "SendCallback success:");
                    if(arg0 == null)
                    {
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    "suceess push notification :");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            Log.d(TAG,
                                    "failed push notification  :"
                                            + arg0.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            
    }
});
```

But I have to set "username"  lets say "a" "b" "c". How will I set multiple username? and how will I resolve issue as it is failed to send notification
LOGCAT :

```
05-19 13:09:28.833: I/System.out(13982): [CDS]close[37294]
05-19 13:09:28.834: I/System.out(13982): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:37294]
05-19 13:09:28.836: I/System.out(13982): ex:org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
05-19 13:09:28.836: I/System.out(13982): retry1
05-19 13:09:28.853: D/libc-netbsd(13982): getaddrinfo: api.parse.com get result from proxy >>
```

Comment: I would suggest you not use `User user = new User()` to "create" a new user. Even via this way what you did is not correct. You should use `ParseUser`. I think Parse.com documentation suggest you use query to locate the user, could you try that?

Comment: kindly check my edit question i am using this code i m not using user user = new User(); !@ss1271

Comment: this `whereMatchesQuery` line, you should use lower case "user" other than the uppercase. Should be something like this:`query.whereMatchesQuery("user", userQuery);`

Comment: wait device is on charge let me check and if i want to pass array of users then ??? means i want to send multiple user name ? then how will i pass @ss1271

Comment: Use parse query to perform a "OR" query. Please do check the parse documentation, they have a method to allow you do a "OR"

Comment: @ss1271  done but no luck not getting notification one thing more will it not send notification from android to ios device ???

Comment: I'm getting confused. could you maybe update your question with more detailed information? Maybe I can do some help later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78175/discussion-between-erum-and-ss1271).

Comment: @ss1271  pls check my edit code now i m using above code but i m failed to recieve any push notification

Comment: Have you tried the same code without parsePush.setChannel("");

Comment: yes but no luck any idea how to save pointer of one table in another table

Comment: You could add a user field in the installation class and then send the push to those installations

Comment: @user4479807  i already have pointer of user table in Installation table ..... but  i m not getting how to save user pointer in installation class any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: Go to the dashboard and open the installation class.  Then create a new column named user.  Then in the code save the users in the user field and query the installation class to send push messages

Comment: yes the issue is in while saving users in user field how will i  do this @user4479807  can u come in SO chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians