# Responding to Parse Push notifications with a custom response

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an Android app and I wish to use Push notifications to perform a custom task *without* displaying a notification to the user.
Specifically, the app is in alpha stage and I wish to be able to send a remote command to a specific device to restart a background service running in the background.

I know that you can do that with GCM. How can this be done using Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [need to subclass ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and override `onPushReceive()` method in it](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/). Add these lines to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".yourPushReceiverSubclass" android:exported=false>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Just remove call to super in the `onPushReceive` method and do whatever you want. If you going to send push from pars.com in JSON format, you can obtain this message using just like that:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
```

Comment: can u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303082/failed-to-recieve-notification-sending-on-button-click-using-parse-com-android

Comment: @Erum sorry, I can't help with that issue. I've never dived into sending pushes from client as long as it leaves security breaches. Consider writing cloud function that would send pushes from parse.com when you call it. More on this http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/

Comment: can u tell  can we send notification using cloud method by passing username while username is already stored in parse.com database

Comment: @Erum exactly. Calling functions to make some actions for you it's the best way to reduce number of opportunitites for malicious user to hijack your app and make unauthorized actions. Also you could make additional actions on your db apart from sending pushes when calling cloud functions

Comment: can u pls come here i m just getting issue to write method in cloud where will i write this method can u kindly come here  ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab or any SO android chat group and kindly ping me